# Tp-Link T2600G-28TS GPL Source Code Compiling Error

Tags: linux, u-boot, buildroot

i am trying to build t2600g-28ts switch's u-boot and buildroot linux
to get bootloader for modifying device my next goal is flashing OpenWRT.
It is a bcm53547 based board
I have tried build instructions below and no lucks.
I think may toolchains are the problem so how can i solve the problem .
any help would be appreciated thanks..

**T2600-28TS GPL Codes**
https://static.tp-link.com/resources/gpl/t2600g-28ts_gpl_20181206.tar.gz

**Build Instructions**

```
1. All build targets are in "t2600g-28ts_gpl/tplink/buildroot-wolfhound2/" and "t2600g-28ts_gpl/ldk/XLDK_4.2.1/bootloader/uboot-2016.01", you should enter the directory to build components.

2. Toolchain binary is avaliable in this package. The directory is "t2600g-28ts_gpl/tplink/buildroot-wolfhound2/host/usr/bin/".

3. Building steps:
 1) put t2600g-28ts_gpl in directory /project/trunk
 2) export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/project/trunk/t2600g-28ts_gpl/tplink/buildroot-wolfhound2/host/usr/lib" 
 3) cd /project/trunk/t2600g-28ts_gpl/tplink/buildroot-wolfhound2
 3) make O=./build/t2600g-28ts tplink-t2600g-28ts_defconfig
 4) make O=./build/t2600g-28ts
 After step4 completed, The linux kernel image, rootfs filesystem will be found in directory "t2600g-28ts_gpl/tplink/buildroot-wolfhound2/build/t2600g-28ts/images".
 
 5) cd /project/trunk/t2600g-28ts_gpl/ldk/XLDK_4.2.1/bootloader/uboot-2016.01
 6) export CROSS_COMPILE=/project/trunk/t2600g-28ts_gpl/tplink/buildroot-wolfhound2/host/usr/bin/arm-linux-
 7) export ARCH=arm
 8) export PATH="$PATH:/project/trunk/t2600g-28ts_gpl/tplink/buildroot-wolfhound2/host/usr/bin"
 9) make O=./build-output bcm953547k_defconfig
 10) make O=./build-output all
 After step11 completed, uboot will be found in directory "t2600g-28ts_gpl/ldk/XLDK_4.2.1/bootloader/uboot-2016.01".
```

**My work**

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:~/t2600g-28ts_gpl/tplink/buildroot-wolfhound2/host/usr/lib"
cd ~/t2600g-28ts_gpl/tplink/buildroot-wolfhound2
make O=./build/t2600g-28ts tplink-t2600g-28ts_defconfig
```

**Build Debugs**

```
/usr/bin/install -d -m 0755 /home/topcu/t2600g-28ts_gpl/tplink/buildroot-wolfhound2/build/t2600g-28ts/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabi/sysroot/usr/bin
/usr/bin/install -d -m 0755 /home/topcu/t2600g-28ts_gpl/tplink/buildroot-wolfhound2/build/t2600g-28ts/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabi/sysroot/usr/sbin
/usr/bin/install -d -m 0755 /home/topcu/t2600g-28ts_gpl/tplink/buildroot-wolfhound2/build/t2600g-28ts/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabi/sysroot/usr/include
/usr/bin/install -d -m 0755 /home/topcu/t2600g-28ts_gpl/tplink/buildroot-wolfhound2/build/t2600g-28ts/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabi/sysroot/bin
/usr/bin/install -d -m 0755 /home/topcu/t2600g-28ts_gpl/tplink/buildroot-wolfhound2/build/t2600g-28ts/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabi/sysroot/sbin
/usr/bin/install -d -m 0755 /home/topcu/t2600g-28ts_gpl/tplink/buildroot-wolfhound2/build/t2600g-28ts/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabi/sysroot/lib
ln -snf lib /home/topcu/t2600g-28ts_gpl/tplink/buildroot-wolfhound2/build/t2600g-28ts/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabi/sysroot/lib32
ln -snf lib /home/topcu/t2600g-28ts_gpl/tplink/buildroot-wolfhound2/build/t2600g-28ts/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib32
>>> skeleton undefined Fixing libtool files
>>> skeleton undefined Installing to target
rsync -a --ignore-times  --chmod=u=rwX,go=rX --exclude .empty --exclude '*~' board/broadcom/iproc/skeleton/ /home/topcu/t2600g-28ts_gpl/tplink/buildroot-wolfhound2/build/t2600g-28ts/target/
/usr/bin/install -d -m 0755 /home/topcu/t2600g-28ts_gpl/tplink/buildroot-wolfhound2/build/t2600g-28ts/target/bin
/usr/bin/install -d -m 0755 /home/topcu/t2600g-28ts_gpl/tplink/buildroot-wolfhound2/build/t2600g-28ts/target/sbin
/usr/bin/install -d -m 0755 /home/topcu/t2600g-28ts_gpl/tplink/buildroot-wolfhound2/build/t2600g-28ts/target/lib
ln -snf lib /home/topcu/t2600g-28ts_gpl/tplink/buildroot-wolfhound2/build/t2600g-28ts/target/lib32
ln -snf lib /home/topcu/t2600g-28ts_gpl/tplink/buildroot-wolfhound2/build/t2600g-28ts/target/usr/lib32
/usr/bin/install -m 0644 support/misc/target-dir-warning.txt /home/topcu/t2600g-28ts_gpl/tplink/buildroot-wolfhound2/build/t2600g-28ts/target/THIS_IS_NOT_YOUR_ROOT_FILESYSTEM
>>> toolchain-external undefined Extracting
>>> toolchain-external undefined Patching
>>> toolchain-external undefined Configuring
Cannot execute cross-compiler '/home/topcu/t2600g-28ts_gpl/tplink/buildroot-wolfhound2/host/usr/bin/arm-linux-gcc.br_real'
make[1]: *** [package/pkg-generic.mk:189: /home/topcu/t2600g-28ts_gpl/tplink/buildroot-wolfhound2/build/t2600g-28ts/build/toolchain-external-undefined/.stamp_configured] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:36: _all] Error 2
```

Comment: Does the file it's complaining about (`/home/topcu/t2600g-28ts_gpl/tplink/buildroot-wolfhound2/host/usr/bin/arm-linux-gcc.br_real`) exist? Is it executable?

Comment: Yes it exists . there is symbolic link like this `lrwxrwxrwx 1 alfa alfa 44 Nis 14 15:21 arm-linux-gcc.br_real -> arm-broadcom-linux-uclibcgnueabi-gcc.br_real` when i look du -sh to file > `672K arm-broadcom-linux-uclibcgnueabi-gcc.br_real`

Comment: and arm-broadcom-linux-uclibcgnueabi-gcc.br_real has chmod 755

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I managed to solve it by compiling on CentOS 6.10, but I had to install GCC and some python dependencies first. Now I'm trying to upload as image in EVE-NG